# Get mean of dataframe by groups of fixed length

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with

```
V1     V2 
1      9
1.1    10 
1      10.5
2.01   15
2      14
...
```

I want to get the means of each group of 3 (jumping, not rolling), so result should be:

```
V1     V2 
1.xx   10.xx
2.xx   15.xx
...
```

I dug into `apply`, `rapply` or `aggregate`, but couldn't find how to do this...

Comment: You want a rolling mean or jumping each 3? For rolling mean, take a look at `rollmean` in the zoo package

Comment: @DavidArenburg jumping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df$gr <- as.character(gl(nrow(df),3, nrow(df)))
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(gr) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))

#    gr       V1        V2
#1  1 1.033333  9.833333
#2  2 2.005000 14.500000
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=gr]
#   gr       V1        V2
#1:  1 1.033333  9.833333
#2:  2 2.005000 14.500000
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~gr, df, mean)
#    gr       V1        V2
#1  1 1.033333  9.833333
#2  2 2.005000 14.500000
```

Or `sapply` based approach without using the `gr`

```
t(sapply(seq(1, nrow(df), by=3), function(i){
                   indx <- i:(i+2)
           colMeans(df[indx[indx <=nrow(df)],])}))
 #           V1        V2
 #[1,] 1.033333  9.833333
 #[2,] 2.005000 14.500000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1.1, 1, 2.01, 2), V2 = c(9, 10, 10.5, 
15, 14)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Nice `gl` implementation

Comment: thanks, wish it was simpler; can't using `reshape` and then `apply` a bit better?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I was updating it :-)

Comment: @CharlesB, both `reshape` and `apply` are `for` loops, and (unlike other languages) R doesn't like `for` loops. akrun provided a vectorized solution which will be much more efficient by many factors.

Comment: @CharlesB I think `dplyr` and `data.table` codes are pretty simple too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't have much data, so I can afford less efficient stuff. Would it be easier to read?

Comment: @CharlesB Do you find `aggregate(.~gr, df, mean)` hard to read?

Comment: oh, haven't seen this one :-)